# Topology Book including specific aspects

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, topological-vector-spaces, book-recommendation, locally-convex-spaces

I am looking for a basic book about Topology (maybe also a bit of Functional analysis but basically Topology) including the following points (in addition to the basic points):

$\bullet$ Seminorms

$\bullet$ Locally convex topological vector spaces

$\bullet$ weak-$^{*}$ topology

Comment: You probably want to look for a book on topological vector spaces, not general topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~lwmarcou/Preprints/LinearAnalysis.pdf

This was the book used for my functional analysis course. It is a functional text more than a topology text book, but has chapters on those 3 bullets you listed and other related topics. I liked it very much.

Comment: Link in answer is dead (*404 Not Found*).